# Problems with compiling Android Oreo ROM. "C_INCLUDES must be under the source...."

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build Android Oreo with this device tree:

https://github.com/BirdSanctuary/device_xiaomi_mido.

Short after I start compilation I have following error

```
build/core/binary.mk:1459: error: 
device/xiaomi/mido/camera/QCamera2/Android.mk: 
camera.msm8953: C_INCLUDES must be under the source or output
directories: /libstagefrighthw /mm-core/inc /libqservice.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Open device/xiaomi/mido/camera/QCamera2/Android.mk and look for

`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
        $(SRC_DISPLAY_HAL_DIR)/libqservice`

`SRC_DISPLAY_HAL_DIR` is not defined anywhere os it looks in root of your filesystem `/libqservcie`
rather then somewhere like this:

`./hardware/qcom/display/msm8909/libqservice
./hardware/qcom/display/msm8084/libqservice
./hardware/qcom/display/msm8994/libqservice
./hardware/qcom/display/msm8998/libqservice
./hardware/qcom/display/msm8226/libqservice
./hardware/qcom/display/msm8960/libqservice
./hardware/qcom/display/msm8996/libqservice`

as you see you have many hw options many HAL's modules for different. I don't know which one you need.
You need to define it somewhere in device/ for your vendor and board specific files.

The same story is for the rest of directories your error printout 'shouts'.

You have undefined make variables in that Android.mk

Answer (score 1):

use like this
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../to/header/file/path/

Do not use direct path.

Answer (score 0):

Usually android source code contains different target variant.

So, you need to select one before starting the build.

Here is the setps.

step 1: Initialize the environment with the envsetup.sh script from /build/envsetup.sh

> source build/envsetup.sh

step 2: Choose which target to build with lunch.

> lunch product_name-build_variant

example:

> lunch aosp_arm-eng

If you don't know the build variant/target variant just type `lunch` command it will list all the available variant that can be build.

step 3: Now start the build.

> make -j16

Note: The above steps need to be followed for every reboot.